# Cannot find module 'asap/raw'

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

i have started a new react-native project and after that i installed `react-native-maps` i can't run `react-native run-android` because the terminal displays the following error:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'asap/raw'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/valentino/Scrivania/lolo/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Module._compile (/home/valentino/Scrivania/lolo/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/valentino/Scrivania/lolo/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
```

The message is shown if i install `react-native-maps`, this is the command with i have built the project with:

```
react-native init appName
cd appName
npm install react-native-maps --save
react-native run-android
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Running `npm install` in your project directory should work.

Comment: thanks you, now it work

Comment: @EighteenthVariable thanks it helped. Please make it an answer so I can upvote it

Comment: @Val Happy my answer helped :)
Done.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Running `npm install` in your project directory usually works.

(What it does is that it [installs all the dependencies in the local node_modules folder](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) that may have been downloaded when you installed that one package.)

Comment: By "project directory" do you mean inside the ios/android folder or the main folder of the React-Native project which contains ios and android folders?

Comment: @nr5 the latter (aka the main folder)

Answer (score 8):

Running `npm install` did not solve the problem for me.

I ran `npm install -g asap` to install asap and then the error went away.

Answer (score 7):

The `react-native init` command creates a project which uses `yarn` by default since `0.57` (has `yarn.lock`). I had the same error when I installed a plugin by `npm install`, so the conclusion is that you can't use both package manager for the same project at the same time (yarn and npm). So:

- Use `yarn add` instead of `npm install`.
- Or if you don't want to use yarn, then "switch" to npm by running `npm install` first (after this you can delete `yarn.lock` and you must always use npm from this point instead of yarn).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting node_modules and reinstalling didn't fix but doing `npm install asap` in the project directory fixed my issue.